# ios UICollectionView layout (margin and move of sections)

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

what I want is like this:
[image]

As you can see, the second section's first bubble is margined by some space in the left.

What I have now is:
[image]

I am using UICollectionView, and I think the answer should be something about UICollectionViewFlowLayout. So I want to know:
(1) how to make the even rows have the left margin
(2) how to make the even rows lifted up but a little after adding the left margin to it.

Thank you very much!! Please help me out!!

Comment: Give reference to helpful tutorials specific in this problem is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the Cell of the collection view is in an even row (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. Then add a padding to its position.

Comment: How about moving up?

Comment: I think I need to extend a new layout from UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Comment: each view has a frame which can be modified. so you can simply set that to whatever you like: yourView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height). Increase the y value and you can move it up.

Comment: also: you seem to make a game. why don't you use SpriteKit (https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/) for that purpose?

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion first. 

Because this is a school project and they don't allow SprikeKit for educational purpose.

Comment: Awesome! It works! You save my day! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad i could help and hope you get a good grade on that one :)